# Uniformly distributed numbers within a range of [-1,1], [-2,2] and so on

Tags: c, random

In C, how can you generate uniformly distributed (double) numbers within a range of [-1,1], [-2,2] and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Needed somewhere in beginning:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

And function:

```
double Rand(double min, double max)
{
    return rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX - 1) * (max - min) + min;
}
```

---

So you can call this something like:

```
Rand(-2, 2);
```

Or make another function:

```
double Rand (double limit)
{
    return Rand(-limit, limit);
}
```

Comment: what I did is: delta = (double) rand()/ RAND_MAX * (dB_mean_error_max - dB_mean_error_min) + dB_mean_error_min; and it gives me the numbers in the specific range. I am not sure about the uniform distribution, but I think that rand()/RAND_MAX is uniformly distributed.

Comment: @ST3: Putting brackets for clarity may be needed?

Comment: @legends2k well, not sure if it is necessary as everything is performed in given order.